# How to align icon to left and text to the right of it

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know how to produce something like this using CSS and HTML?

[image]

I tried it myself, but it looks like this:

[image]

Here's what I have so far:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.bar {
  background: #0f0f0f;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 25px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.icon {
  font-size: x-large;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
}

.text {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <a href="https://example.com" target="_blank">
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-folder"></i></div>
      <div class="text"><b>Title</b><br>Description.</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: either use `Flexbox` or `CSS-Grid` to align boxes next to each other. Alternativly you could use `display: inline-block;`

Comment: I believe I used CSS grid, do you know how to change the sizes of each individual box in the grid?

Comment: see my anwser. change this line: `.bar { grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); }`  to `.bar { grid-template-columns: repeat(2, min-content); }`  and it will be solved.

Comment: @tacoshy: Dear Mate! min-content: will make sure the width the column stays as minimum as the content. If any new content is added on the column then this will increase the height of the container :) Hope you got my point ^^^ Happy coding

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather which could be coutnered with `white-space: nowrap;` in a more complicated design matter. Which is not the case here. Alternativly with `grid-template-columns: min-content auto;`. For other scenarios different solutions might apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use flex, it's easier

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.bar {
  background: pink;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 25px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:flex-start;
}

.icon {
  font-size: x-large;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
  border:solid 2px red;
}

.text {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <a href="https://example.com" target="_blank">
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-folder"></i></div>
      <div class="text"><b>Title</b><br>Description.</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Its one way, not really easier. the CSS-Grid solution he already used has just one mistake. `1fr` simply needs to be replaced with `min-content`.

Comment: your icon in your solution doesn't take up 25% of the space

Answer (score 6):

As you already use CSS-Grid, I will go with it. you just need to change a single line:

`.bar { grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); }`

to

`.bar { grid-template-columns: repeat(2, min-content); }`

`min-content` will take only as much space as needed. `1fr`, will take 1 fraction (in this case 50%) of the box width.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.bar {
  background: #0f0f0f;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 25px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, min-content);
}

.icon {
  font-size: x-large;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
}

.text {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <a href="https://example.com" target="_blank">
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-folder"></i></div>
      <div class="text"><b>Title</b><br>Description.</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Added the font awesome library and gave you the upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `display:grid;` on `.bar` of equal width columns that's why they are far apart.

Simple `flex;` property on bar automatically gets items side by side by default. That would do it.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.bar {
  background: #0f0f0f;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 25px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;/* only if required to set times to center vertically*/
}

.icon {
  font-size: x-large;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
}

.text {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="https://example.com" target="_blank">
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-folder"></i></div>
      <div class="text"><b>Title</b><br>Description.</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```